# In PHP(Codeigniter) After inserting few data in Mongodb insertion is getting slow

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

In Mongodb after inserting few data insertion is getting slow, i am using batch_insert for insertion. While inserting i need to check some conditions also.

To insert 20k data itself takes more than 1 hour.

In temporary_table i am having 1L data

```
$batchSize = 20;
$documents = array();
$count = count($pending_contacts_data);
$count =1;
$temporary_data = array();

for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

  $multiple_temporary_data = $this->mongo_db->select('*')->where(array('contact_id'=>(int)4,'status'=>1))->limit(10000)->get('temporary_table');
  $temporary_data = array_merge($temporary_data,$multiple_temporary_data);
}

$count1 = count($temporary_data);
$documents = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$count1; $i++)
{

  $obj_id[] = $temporary_data[$i]->_id;
  $test_email = $this->mongo_db->select('*')->where(array('encrypted_email'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_email))->get('email_table');

  if(empty($test_email)){
    $document = array('email_id'=>$temporary_data[$i]->email,
                      'encrypted_email'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_email,
                      'encrypted_key'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_key,
                      'encrypted_iv'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_iv,
                      'status'=>(int)1,
                      'opend_supression_status'=>''
                     );
      array_push($documents, $document);

    if ((($i % $batchSize) === 0)) {

          $insert = $this->mongo_db->batch_insert('opend_contacts_email_new1',$documents);
          $update_temporary  =$this->mongo_db->where_in('_id',$obj_id)->set(array('status'=>13))->update_all('temporary_data');
          $documents = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure the reason of slowness but what u can try is debugging but start removing the select query and try simple batch insert

Comment: We are using batch_insert to insert 500 documents each time, sorry i didn't get debugging means can u plz explain it.@MarcelDjaman

Comment: Just remove the select query and see what u get

Comment: And reduce the batch size to 20 or 50

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What went wrong with your code is after the 500th element each new item acted as single batch insert. And $documents are just array of one element for the rest of loop. U should have used the modulus operator `%`

```
$count = 20000;
$batchSize = 50;

for ($i=1; $i<=$count; ++$i){

  $test_email = $this->mongo_db->select('*')->where(array('email_id'=>$temporary_data[$i]->email_id))->get('email_table');

  if(empty($test_email)){
    $document = array('email_id'=>$temporary_data[$i]->email,
                          'encrypted_email'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_email,
                          'encrypted_key'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_key,
                          'encrypted_iv'=>$temporary_data[$i]->encrypted_iv,
                          'status'=>(int)1,
                          'suppression_status'=>''
    );
    array_push($documents, $document);

    if (($i % $batchSize) === 0) {         
          $insert = $this->mongo_db->batch_insert('email_table',$documents);
          $documents = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,I tried inserting with the help of above method i took batch size as 20,
it is inserting fine,but i have one problem
i am trying to insert 1L data with 10K for each split, for the first 10K documents it took 2 mins to insert,for the next 10K took 5 mins, next 10k it took 8 mins, i want to know the reason for the delay(i am using mongodb) @Marcel Djaman

Comment: As I said in the comments on your try a simple insert with the select statement and see how long it takes to fulfill the task

Comment: Paste yr full code maybe slowness come from elsewhere. Where did u define the vars `$temporary_data`

Comment: I have added my complete code, please go through it @Marcel Djaman

Comment: ok try to comment the update statement line. And check time it took

Comment: no feedback! Hope u solve it. If u think answer leads to right way can u plz mark it as the answer to your question